# .NET Exception Handling Application Configuration File

Tags: c#, exception, app-config

I apologize as this question is somewhat basic; however, after a great deal of searching, I have not found a suitable answer.  I am building a windows forms application and need to reference an app.config file for the location to a data file.  Before calling

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EntityData"].ToString());
```

I want to ensure that the app.config file exists.  I have tried multiple methods but it seems that it is a lot more work then it should be.  For example I have been trying to use the following code to determine the path for the file

```
        Uri uri = new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
        string fullConfigurationFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.AbsolutePath), configurationFilename);
```

but I run into issues with spaces in the path.  Is there a better way to check for the existence of the app.config, do I even need to check?

Thank you

Comment: Just go access the configuration data. If the file is missing, an exception will be thrown, giving details of what's wrong.

Comment: yeah if you really want to check that put a try catch when accessing the AppSettings file and take it from there

Comment: True, except you would likely access application settings throughout the application, so that can be a mess.

Comment: So that I am clear, if a user were to delete app.config file this would not throw an exception if I leverage the ConfigurationManager without checking for the existence of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to verify that the config file exists. The following code should work without exceptions:

```
string temp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EntityData"];
if (temp != null)
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(temp);
}
```

Note that `AppSettings` will return a string if the key is found, so you don't need to call `ToString` to convert it. If the key does not exist, you should instead get a `null` reference that you can test for.

Comment: An exception occurs if the config file is not there.  I can handle the exception, but it seems like a more robust solution would ensure that it is there before relying on the exception handling.

Comment: @lansinwd: are you sure? I tried out the above code both with the config file not being preset, the file existing but without an `appSettings` section and with the `appSettings` section present but without the key in question. In none of these cases did it throw an exception but rather just returned `null`. I made these tests in a Console application; perhaps other application types results in different behavior.

Comment: Thanks for writing back.  I tried this on a pc last night on a windows forms application (C#) in VS2005 and did not recieve any exceptions.  However, when I tried it again today in VS2008, it threw an exception when I deleted the config file and ran the executable.

Comment: @Fredrik Mork - You are correct, after reviewing my code the exception was coming from a later section in the code.  It would seem checking for the existence of the app.config is not needed

Answer (score 1):

System.Configuration should do all of this work for you.  There shouldn't be a need to manually load a config file.